# Sublime Text console window

Tags: windows, sublime-text

How do I change the setting of sublime text so that when I build "control+B", with python, the result of the process is displayed in a pop-up console?

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

The Sublime Text console can't be popped out of the main Window. However, you could run the build command in your default Terminal. In order to do so, you need to create your own custom build system (see `Tools > Build System > New Build System…`).

Here's an adaptation of the original build file for Python:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "cmd /k python -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",

    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},


    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Syntax Check",
            "shell_cmd": "cmd /k python -m py_compile \"${file}\"",
        }
    ]
}
```